# how to change selection and hide selection marker

Tags: javascript, android, selection

I want to "move around" the caret in the page (more specifically inside a contenteditable div) and I use Javascript Selection/Range for this.
The code is pretty simple:

```js
var s = document.getSelection();
var t = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
if (!s.containsNode(t, false)) {
  var r = document.createRange();
  r.selectNodeContents(t);
  r.collapse(false);
  s.addRange(r);
}
```

this successfully moved the caret (cursor) to the desired position (end of the content)

the problem is: *sometimes* Android will also show the selection marker, which is slow and annoying...

how to avoid this?

**Edit** :
I'm targetting apache cordova so:

- a solution which implies native code is ok
- this is targetted at mobile (android/iOS) webview rather then the browser